# Bootstrap 3 collapse “data-parent” not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to use Bootstrap 3 collapse function to design a table to show two different HTML form. There is a problem, if i click form1, form1 can display correctly ,but if i click form2, form2 will show in under form1.

I want when opening form2, form1 will be close and just show out form2.I try to use data-parent , but it still not work.

I'm using the following HTML code:

```
 <div id="myAccordion" >
                <table id="edit" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-nonfluid1 thumbnail" >
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=50%><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form1" data-parent="#myAccordion">form1</button></td>
                        <td width=50%><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form2" data-parent="#myAccordion">form2</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div id="form1" class="collapse">
                            . <form  method="POST"  novalidate="novalidate">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="number1" class="control-label ">number1</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number1" name="number1" >
                                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="number2" class="control-label ">number2</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number2" name="number2" >
                                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="number3" class="control-label ">number3</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number3" name="number3" >
                                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                            <div id="form2" class="collapse">
                                . <form  method="POST"  novalidate="novalidate">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="newinfo" class="control-label ">info</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="newinfo" name="newinfo"> </textarea>
                                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">submit</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

What problem in my code?

Comment: fiddle is must have for html questions

Comment: The collapse is work but “data-parent” is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making use of javascript methods given by bootstrap, made few changes to the code.

HTML

```
<div id="myAccordion" >
            <table id="edit" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-nonfluid1 thumbnail" >
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width=50%><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"  data-parent="#myAccordion" id="form1btn">form1</button></td>
                    <td width=50%><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  data-parent="#myAccordion" id="form2btn">form2</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div id="form1" class="collapse">
                        . <form  method="POST"  novalidate="novalidate">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="number1" class="control-label ">number1</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number1" name="number1" >
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="number2" class="control-label ">number2</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number2" name="number2" >
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="number3" class="control-label ">number3</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number3" name="number3" >
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                        <div id="form2" class="collapse">
                            . <form  method="POST"  novalidate="novalidate">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="newinfo" class="control-label ">info</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="newinfo" name="newinfo"> </textarea>
                                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Below is the Javascript

```
$('#form1btn').click(function(){
$('#form1').collapse('show');
if ( $('#form2').is(':visible'))
$('#form2').collapse('hide');
});
 $('#form2btn').click(function(){
 $('#form2').collapse('show');
  if ( $('#form1').is(':visible'))
 $('#form1').collapse('hide');
 });
```

find it here..

http://jsfiddle.net/mawd59e3/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap dropdown.

HTML------------

```
<nav class="my_style navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS----------

```
.my_style .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu{
    position:relative;
}
```

You can visit this [bootplay](http://www.bootply.com/9D00FL54lw) demo.

Comment: I still want to use collapse in my case because it more fit my website design.If i want to use bootstrap collapse, how can i do?

Comment: I am not so expert. But I think it's may be not possible by this way. you can try it by jquery. It's simple. Just show() and hide().